# How to mark a Grails 3 app as distributable?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm using Grails 3.2.3.  Since support for web.xml was discontinued in Grails 3, how do I mark my application as distributable so it can be clustered in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

A web application can be configured to be distributed in a cluster. You can see this-

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2009719

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that in Grails 3.x, the web.xml file is not used.  My clumsy work around is to extract all files from my war file, manually add a web.xml file that contains only the distributable element, then repackage my war file for deployment.  I was hoping to find a more elegant way to do this within Grails.